# Iam getting this exception of gc out of memory .i tried my option but my app hangs becuse of this

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, garbage-collection, build.gradle

> UNEXUNPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC
>   overhead limit exceeded

added this to gradle

```
dexOptions { 
   incremental true 
   javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}
```

i tried this which hangs the app when i choose the image chooser.It gets into unresponsive.
this problem occurred after i have used the firebase library in my app

Comment: are you using `Instant Run` if yes then just `disable` it.

Comment: use largeheap = true into your manifest file , it will help you

Comment: it does not solve the problem still same error